# Equivalent of CGRectInfinite & CGRectIsInfinite in MonoTouch/Xamarin

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am trying to convert an open source flyout menu from Objective-C to Xamarin. The current issue I have is that the Obj-C code creates a frame using `CGRectInfinite`. This does not appear to be available under MonoTouch, via the usual `RectangleF` class. Is there an alternative?

Similarly, there does not appear to be a `CGRectIsInfinite` equivalent in `RectangleF`. What, if any, is the alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this using statement first:

```
using MonoTouch.CoreGraphics;
```

Then you can test it with this:

```
public static RectangleF GetInfinite()
{
    var image = CIImage.EmptyImage;

    if (image.Extent.IsInfinite ())
    {
        return image.Extent;
    }

    throw new Exception ("Unable to create infinite rect");
}
```

Comment: It's the IsInfinite () method. 'image.Extent' is a RectangleF.